# close popup after click / submit button trigger in mailchimp

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The opt in is catchy and effective I believed but the UX is bad. The user has to manually close the pop-up even after he submitted the email.

How to close the pop up after user submitted the email? Maybe make it delay 1-2 sec after telling the email received.

demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Evsmb

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    (function($) {
        window.fnames = new Array();
        window.ftypes = new Array();
        fnames[0]='EMAIL';
        ftypes[0]='email';
        window.mc.showPopup = true;
        window.mc.delayPopup = 2000;
        if (mc.showPopup) mc.evalPopup();
    }(jQuery));
    var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
//Listen for form submit
$('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').submit(function (e) {

    //hide popup 
    $("#mc_embed_signup").hide();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9qP5/

Answer (score 0):

If you explore the [MailChimp's EvilPopup JavaScript file](http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js) or rather just run `console.log(mc);` from the Console in Firefox/Chrome.

You'll notice that the script provides <s>a success callback `mce_success_cb()`</s> (`mce_success_cb()` is the `ajaxOptions.success` callback handler. `ajaxOptions.complete` is unused and available) `ajaxOptions.complete` and the `closePopup()` function to close the popup.

So you can achieve your goal by the following code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function($) {
    window.fnames = new Array();
    window.ftypes = new Array();
    fnames[0]='EMAIL';
    ftypes[0]='email';
    window.mc.ajaxOptions.complete = function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            // Only close the popup if there are no errors
            if($('#mce-error-response').is(':hidden'))
                window.mc.closePopup();
        }, 2000);
        // 2000ms delay before closing popup
    };
    window.mc.showPopup = true;
    window.mc.delayPopup = 2000;
    if (mc.showPopup) mc.evalPopup();
}(jQuery));
var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

*Please note that `mc.closePopup()` also sets the cookie `MCEvilPopupClosed` with an expiry period of +1 year which prevents the popup from popping up automatically again in the above script which uses the function `mc.evalPopup()` to conditionally display the popup based on the cookie.*

*If you wish to forcefully display the popup even when the `MCEvilPopupClosed` cookie is set, on click of a button for example, use `window.mc.delayPopup = 0; window.mc.openPopup();`.*

*Setting `mc.delayPopup` to 0 ensures that the popup is shown instantly.*

Answer (score 0):

Prathamesh Gharat's answer worked really well for me, with one tweak: checking if `#mce-success-response` is visible, rather than checking if `#mc-error-response` is hidden.

For whatever reason, entering certain types of malformed email addresses (like fake@nodotanything) hides `#mce-error-response` without generating an `#mce-success-response`.

The changed code would look like this:

```
window.mc.ajaxOptions.complete = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Only close the popup if there is a successful response
        if($('#mce-success-response').is(':visible'))
            window.mc.closePopup();
    }, 2000);
    // 2000ms delay before closing popup
};
```